# Why is it that variable re-declaration is not an error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(){
    var bar = 3
    return bar;
    var bar = 8
}
alert(foo());  //prints 3
```

Doing something like this in C++ would throw an error. What was the motive behind making this design decision?

Comment: -C++ tag because it's not a C++ question. The same happens in Java or C#.

Comment: *"What was the motive behind making this design decision?"* This question can't be usefully answered except by Brendan Eich, or by someone citing something (with a valid, verifiable reference) where Brendan Eich explained why he did this. The [relevant part of the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5) is clear that the behavior is defined, but doesn't explain the motive. We can all *speculate*, but speculation isn't what SO is for.

Comment: Who knows why? All web technologies are overly tolerant because they must cope with a large range of bad software and stupid developers. You could also have two <body>s in your HTML. Not one browser would complain.

Answer (score 1):

Because of how JavaScript's function scope and hoisting works, that code is essentially evaluated as:

```
function foo() {
  var bar;
  bar = 3;
  return bar;
  bar = 8;
}
alert(foo());
```

All variable declarations are hoisted up to the top of their scope when parsed and then the assignments happen at runtime, so essentially it doesn't matter if you declare the variable multiple times - the runtime environment doesn't know.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is *"What was the motive behind making this design decision?"* The hoisting is irrelevant, there's no reason you can't have hoisting *and* not allow redundant `var`.

Comment: I suppose there are two design decisions being referenced here. A) Hoisting, and B) The fact that "redeclaring" variables is not a syntax error (which was specifically asked in the question). It seems the reasoning behind B is A. There is no reason to throw a syntax error if the declarations are hoisted to the top at parse time.

Comment: Perhaps. This is not, however, an answer to the question -- or at least, if it is, it's speculative. (In fact, a fair bit of grief could have been avoided if it were an error.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well said sir

Comment: I can also interpret hoisting as: 
function foo() {
  var bar;
  var bar;
  bar = 3;
  return bar;
  bar = 8;
}
alert(foo());
just a naive example, but the point remains: variable are being re-declared.

Answer (score -2):

Any program is basically processed by the computer in three steps:

1. parsing, where the source is being read and converted into an AST. If this is not possible, you get a syntax error.
2. compiling, converting an AST to a runnable representation (machine code, bytecode etc). On error, you get a compilation error.
3. running, possibly getting some runtime errors.

"Static" languages like C++ or Java are designed to raise as many errors as possible on step 2. Programmers love that: every fixed compiler error means less debugging later.

"Scripting" languages like Javascript usually don't raise any compile-time errors at all. Every error you get is either a syntax or a runtime error. Since variable declarations are handled by the compiler, and not at run time, it wouldn't make sense to add a whole new class of errors just for this specific case.